# Why is the Function Returning an Empty String

Tags: c++, string

Why is this function always returning an empty string?

I'm aware of scope of variables but I thought the function would return a copy of the std::string res?

```
string getNumberOfLines(string absFilePath)
{
    int nLines = 0;
    ifstream inFile(absFilePath.c_str());

    if (!inFile)
        return "no lines";

    char c;
    while (inFile.get(c))
    {
        if (c == '\n')
            nLines++;
    }   

    string res;
    sprintf(&res[0], "%d lines.", nLines);
    puts(res.c_str()); // prints "40 lines" or etc.
    return res;
}

puts(getNumberOfLines("f.txt").c_str()); // outputs nothing
```

Comment: `func(const string absFilePath)` will copy the string, but `func(const string& absFilePath)` won't. `sprintf` cannot be used with `std::string` in this way. `&res[0]` is out of bounds as the string is empty. A good debug compiler will flag this for you. Use `std::cin` instead.

Comment: @NeilKirk Thanks for your advice. Does `func(string absFilePath)` also copy the string? I've often seen `func(const string& absFilePath)` - why have it constant why not just pass by reference normally?

Comment: The `&` is what prevents the copy of the string. The const is to prevent accidentally modifying the string passed to the function from outside. The caller may want to reuse it for something else and, as it is an input parameter, not expect it to be changed by the function.

Comment: @NeilKirk ah I see now, thats what I was worried about - the function altering the string. So const ensures the function wont change their string and pass by reference is for efficiency (no copy made). Is the efficiency achieved at compile time or runtime?

Comment: The string may not be known until runtime so this is a runtime optimization.

Comment: It's not naughty to use `std::string` with C functions by using the `c_str` function, and it's often the easiest approach when you have to deal with legacy code. However, make sure nothing modifies the string through the pointer returned by `c_str`. When writing new code, try to stick consistently with C++ approaches unless there is a special reason not to.

Comment: personally I'm a fan of using a [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) and [boost.format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/format/) when I need to do `printf`ish things

Answer (score 2):

You're using `reference std::basic_string::operator[](size_t pos)` to get the first element in a string and then its address using the `&` operator. However, as per the function's specification, if `pos == size` then it's undefined behaviour. C++11 standard, draft N3337, **[string.access]**, `basic_string` element access (emphasis mine):

> 1 *Requires:* `pos <= size()`.
>
> 2 *Returns:* `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`. Otherwise, returns a reference to an object of type `charT` with value `charT()`, where **modifying the object leads to undefined behavior**.

Your string `res` has no elements in it and is thus 0 sized, thus undefined behaviour ensues. After this point, nothing else is guarenteed by the language.

You should be using `std::ostringstream` for this:

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << nLines << " lines.";
auto res = ss.str();
std::cout << res << '\n';
return res;
```

Comment: as is standard (no pun intended) for any c++ question, can you quote the standard for this?

Comment: @Mgetz Why do we have to quote the standard for every thing? That would be very tedious.

Comment: @NeilKirk: We don't. Only those things for which standard-mandates are asserted. Providing evidence is _always_ better than not doing so.

Comment: @Mgetz There you go! However, I agree with Kirk here, for the obvious ones it's sometimes an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are trying to write into an empty string.

When you create a `std::string`, no storage is allocated, so you are passing the address of a zero-length array to `sprintf`.

Comment: *"you are passing the address of a zero-length array"* Hm I'm not sure about this. The state has become undefined before that point.

Comment: "Don't use C++" isn't a logical answer to "What's the best practice in C++?"

Comment: @kuroineko your post violated the stackoverflow posting guidelines because it was a rant and not an answer. LRIO was nice enough to remove the rant and leave only the answerish bits that are actually relevant to the question.

Comment: "Censored"? Calm down.

Comment: @NeilKirk I'm surprised our C++ valkirye did not correct this intolerable inaccuracy herself. Indeed, `&res[0]` is an UB, so the compiler is free to paint your mustache pink when it encounters it.